# Snap-store and Chromium don't open

Tags: snap, chromium

I have some problem with snap-store and chromium: after start they can't open. Gnome-software is working. If run applications in terminal, in both cases i receive the error

"Inconsistency detected by ld.so: ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h: 541: elf_machine_rela_relative: Assertion `ELFW(R_TYPE) (reloc->r_info) == R_X86_64_RELATIVE' failed!"

System is update, reboot machine doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. To fix this you have to open the system monitor which comes preinstalled in ubuntu. Then in it scroll down and find the apps which are not opening. Then right click the application and then click on restart program. If this doesn't fix your problem then reinstall the programs.

Comment: And how i find this apps? There are many processes

Comment: Problem is solved: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install snapd chromium-browser`